# Binding color property from xaml to c#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I am trying to bind a property of a self made control from my view to my viewmodel. When I bind the color directly to another element in the xaml, it works but when i try to bind it to a property in my viewmodel. There is not change in property.

xaml:

```
<StackPanel>
    <Border Height="50"
            BorderBrush="Black"
            BorderThickness="1">
        <Border.Background>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding color}" />
        </Border.Background>
    </Border>
    <Border Height="50"
            BorderBrush="Black"
            BorderThickness="1">
        <Border.Background>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding ElementName=colorCircle, Path=selectedColor}" />
        </Border.Background>
    </Border>

    <local:ColorCircle x:Name="colorCircle" selectedColor="{Binding color, Mode=OneWayToSource}" />

</StackPanel>
```

.cs:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Color _color;
    public Color color
    {
        get { return _color; }
        set
        {
            _color = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("color");
        }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        DataContext = this;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected virtual void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

**ColorWheel**

xaml:

```
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center"
      VerticalAlignment="Center"
      Background="Transparent">

    <Image x:Name="ColorImage"
           Width="300"
           Height="300"
           HorizontalAlignment="Center"
           VerticalAlignment="Top"
           RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality"
           Source="color_wheel.png" />

    <Canvas x:Name="CanvImage"
            Width="300"
            Height="300"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Background="Transparent">

        <Ellipse Width="300"
                 Height="300"
                 HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                 VerticalAlignment="Top"
                 Fill="Transparent"
                 MouseDown="Ellipse_MouseDown"
                 MouseMove="Ellipse_MouseMove"
                 MouseUp="Ellipse_MouseUp" />
        <Ellipse x:Name="ellipsePixel"
                 Canvas.Left="150"
                 Canvas.Top="150"
                 Width="10"
                 Height="10"
                 Fill="Transparent"
                 MouseDown="Ellipse_MouseDown"
                 MouseMove="Ellipse_MouseMove"
                 MouseUp="Ellipse_MouseUp"
                 Stroke="Black"
                 StrokeThickness="2" />
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

.cs:

```
public partial class ColorCircle : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedColorProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("selectedColor", typeof(SolidColorBrush), typeof(ColorCircle));

    private SolidColorBrush _selectedColor = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent);
    public SolidColorBrush selectedColor
    {
        get { return (SolidColorBrush)GetValue(SelectedColorProperty); }
        set
        {
            if (_selectedColor != value)
            {
                SetValue(SelectedColorProperty, value);
            }
        }
    }

    private bool __isMouseDown { get; set; } = false;
    private bool _isMouseDown
    {
        get { return __isMouseDown; }
        set
        {
            __isMouseDown = value;
            if (__isMouseDown) ColorSelect();
        }
    }

    public ColorCircle()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
    }

    private void ColorSelect()
    {
        try
        {
            CroppedBitmap cb = new CroppedBitmap(ColorImage.Source as BitmapSource,
                new Int32Rect((int)Mouse.GetPosition(CanvImage).X,
                    (int)Mouse.GetPosition(CanvImage).Y, 1, 1));

            byte[] pixels = new byte[4];

            try
            {
                cb.CopyPixels(pixels, 4, 0);
            }
            catch (Exception) { }

            ellipsePixel.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, Mouse.GetPosition(CanvImage).X - 5);
            ellipsePixel.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, Mouse.GetPosition(CanvImage).Y - 5);
            CanvImage.InvalidateVisual();
            selectedColor = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, pixels[2], pixels[1], pixels[0]));

        }
        catch (Exception) { }
    }

    private void Ellipse_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_isMouseDown) ColorSelect();
    }

    private void Ellipse_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        _isMouseDown = true;
    }

    private void Ellipse_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        _isMouseDown = false;
    }
}
```

The `colorcircle` has a `DependencyProperty` `selectedColor` that returns a `Color`. That works. I get the color in the second border but not in the first one...

Comment: could you please remove the irrelevant code...

Comment: this is practicly the same, but still not working...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason it failed. I needed to set the 'Datacontext' of the ColorCircle to the 'DataContext' of 'this'.

```
<local:ColorCircle x:Name="colorCircle"
                       Grid.Row="1"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                       VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                       DataContext="{Binding .}"
                       selectedColor="{Binding selectedColorXaml,
                                               Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

so 'DataContext="{Binding .}"' was the anwser...

Answer (score 4):

The reason your code isn't working is because you are binding the Color Property of SolidColorBrush to a SolidColorBrush property in your ColorPicker ViewModel

Change SelectedColor type to Color

[image]

Main Xaml

```
 <StackPanel>
        <Border Height="50"
            BorderBrush="Black"
            BorderThickness="1">
            <Border.Background>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding color}" />
            </Border.Background>
        </Border>
        <Border Height="50"
            BorderBrush="Black"
            BorderThickness="1">
            <Border.Background>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding ElementName=colorPicker, Path=SelectedColor}" />
            </Border.Background>
        </Border>

        <local:ColorPicker x:Name="colorPicker" />

    </StackPanel>
```

Xaml.CS For Above XAML

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private Color _MyColor;

    public Color MyColor
    {
        get { return _MyColor; }
        set { _MyColor = value; }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {            
        InitializeComponent();
        MyColor = Colors.Orange;
        this.DataContext = this;
    }

}
```

ColorPicker.xaml

```
<Grid>
    <Button Click="Button_Click" Content="Click Me To Change Color"/>
</Grid>
```

ColorPicker.xaml.cs

```
 public partial class ColorPicker : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        List<Color> _myColors = new List<Color>() 
        { Colors.Yellow, Colors.Green, Colors.Orange, Colors.Red };

        public Color SelectedColor
        {
            get { return (Color)GetValue(SelectedColorProperty); }
            set { SetValue(SelectedColorProperty, value); OnPropertyChanged("SelectedColor"); }
        }


        public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedColorProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedColor", typeof(Color), typeof(ColorPicker), new PropertyMetadata(null));        

        public ColorPicker()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            SelectedColor = _myColors[0];
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            int index = _myColors.IndexOf(SelectedColor);
            if (index == _myColors.Count - 1)
            {
                index = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                index++;
            }

            SelectedColor = _myColors[index];
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;


        public void OnPropertyChanged(String propname)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propname));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should check your output window. You likely have a binding expression error. You are binding to SelectedColor which is SolidColorBrush and then you're binding a SolidColorBrush's Color property to it. Your SelectedColor should be of type Color. Refer to my above example

Answer (score 2):

Could you provide a smaller example that doesn't work?

My test (using ReactiveUI for the ViewModel) is working properly.

Xaml:

```
<StackPanel>
    <Grid Height="50">
        <Grid.Background>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Color}" />
        </Grid.Background>
    </Grid>

    <ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding Color, Mode=OneWayToSource}" SelectedIndex="0">
        <Color>Red</Color>
        <Color>Blue</Color>
        <Color>Yellow</Color>
    </ComboBox>
</StackPanel>
```

ViewModel:

```
public class MainViewModel : ReactiveObject
{
    private System.Windows.Media.Color _color;

    public System.Windows.Media.Color Color
    {
        get { return _color; }
        set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _color, value); }
    }
}
```

Comment: i changed the code above to almost the same as your code but I don't use ReactiveUI... For the rest it is the same but doesn't work...

Comment: You have made a little mistake on your new example. On the xaml you bind to Color and on the code behind you have color. If you put both UpperCase or LowerCase, the example is working.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `System.Windows.Media.Brush` instead of `System.Windows.Media.Color` to change colors of `Control`. That is, your property should be:

```
private System.Windows.Media.Brush _selectedColor 
public System.Windows.Media.Brush selectedColorXaml
{
    get { return _selectedColor; }
    set
    {
        _selectedColor = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("selectedColorXaml");
    }
}
```

Just as a little advice, name your property in upper case. Like that:

```
private System.Windows.Media.Brush _selectedColor { get; set; }
public System.Windows.Media.Brush SelectedColorXaml
{
    get { return _selectedColor; }
    set
    {
        _selectedColor = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedColorXaml");
    }
}
```

I've made a test for you and it works:

**viewModel:**

```
public YourViewModel
{
    Timer timer;
    public YourViewModel()
    {
        timer = new Timer(1000);
        timer.Elapsed += Timer_Elapsed;
        timer.Enabled = true;           
    }


    int count = 0;
    private void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(count%2==0)
            FooColor = Brushes.Green;
        else
            FooColor = Brushes.Red;
        count++;
    }

    private Brush fooColor;
    public Brush FooColor           
    {
       get { return fooColor; }
       set
       {
         fooColor = value;
         OnPropertyChanged("FooColor");
       }
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Window
   xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:TreeViewMVVM.ViewModel">
   <Window.DataContext>
      <vm:YourViewModel/>
   </Window.DataContext>
   <Grid>
      <Button Content="Click me!" Background="{Binding FooColor}"/>
   <Grid>
</Window>
```

**Update 2:**

*My problem is that i can't get the selected color from the view back to my viewMode*

At first, you should create property for SelectedItem in your view model:

```
private Color selectedItem=new object();
public Color SelectedItem           
{
   get { return selectedItem; }
   set
   {
      selectedItem = value;//here is you Selected Color
   }
}
```

and in XAML:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="colorBox"
          SelectedIndex="0"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}">
    <Color>Red</Color>
    <Color>Blue</Color>
    <Color>Yellow</Color>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: @WimVanLaer change `selectedColor="{Binding selectedColorXaml,                                               Mode=OneWayToSource, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />` to `TwoWay`. Is your DataContext set correctly?

Comment: I already tried changing the mode of the binding but that didn't work. The DataContext is certainly right, all of the Commands and other bindings work just just fine.

Comment: @WimVanLaer I double checked my code and made a test example for you. Please, see my answer again.

Comment: Thanks for the awnser, your example works just fine but i can send data to my view just fine. My problem is that i can't get the selected color from the view back to my viewModel.

Comment: @WimVanLaer please, see **Update2**

Comment: It works but for some strange reason, it doesn't when i change the combobox to the colorCircle however they both return a color...

Comment: You need to use SolidColorBrush. Please see my answer below

Comment: @WimVanLaer please, see my updated answer. Just change `object` type to `Color` type. Feel free to ask any question.

Comment: Thanks, that works but the strange thing is that it doesn't work with the ColorCircle, while it returns just a Color too...

Comment: @WimVanLaer cause you should create DependencyProperty `SelectedItem` for `ColorCircle`. It will work, when you create DependencyProperty  `SelectedItem` in your  `ColorCircle`.

Comment: The ColorCircle has a 'DependencyProperty' 'selectedColor'. I use that to bind the color/brush