# Sharing Style with DataTrigger depending on bound value

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding

I have searched but not yet found any way on how to do this. I'm also relatively new to XAML and binding.

I have many `TextBlocks` in which the text is bound to a property and have a `StringFormat`:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding PropA, StringFormat=Running {0}"/>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Height, StringFormat=Sub: \{0\}"/>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Depth, StringFormat=Indie: \{0\}"/>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Color, StringFormat=State: \{0\}"/>
```

Now I want to apply a style depending on the value of the bound variable (so the real text being displayed is irrelevant). Currently I have to apply a `<Style>` to every element and use the bound property directly again. This seems cumbersome and prone to copy paste errors. I was wondering if I could define a `<Style>` and share it.

Something like:

```
<Style x:Key="Highlight_Non_Zero">
  <!-- invert the logic because DataTrigger is an equality comparer -->
  <Setter Property="TextBlock.Background" Value="Orange"/>
  <Style.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding <some magic here that gets the element this style applies to bound variable>" Value="0">
      <Setter Property"TextBlock.Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    </DataTrigger>
  </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

<TextBlock Text="{Binding PropA, StringFormat=Running {0}" Style="{StaticResource Highlight_Non_Zero}"/>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Height, StringFormat=Sub: \{0\}" Style="{StaticResource Highlight_Non_Zero}"/>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Depth, StringFormat=Indie: \{0\}" Style="{StaticResource Highlight_Non_Zero}"/>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Color, StringFormat=State: \{0\}" Style="{StaticResource Highlight_Non_Zero}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use attached property to pass something *common* (e.g. `bool` value) into style:

```
public class TextBlockBehavior
{
    public static bool GetMyProperty(DependencyObject obj) => (bool)obj.GetValue(MyPropertyProperty);
    public static void SetMyProperty(DependencyObject obj, bool value) => obj.SetValue(MyPropertyProperty, value);

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyPropertyProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("MyProperty", typeof(bool), typeof(TextBlockBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(false));
}
```

Then each `TextBlock` can set value of it from different sources:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding PropA, StringFormat=Running \{0\}}"
           local:TextBlockBehavior.MyProperty="{Binding PropA ...}"
           Style="{StaticResource Highlight_Non_Zero}" />
```

Note: you have to use converter or another property in ViewModel to make properties of various type (in your case `PropA`, `Color`, `Depth`, etc.) setting  value of `bool MyProperty`.

And then in style you can use it:

```
<Style x:Key="Highlight_Non_Zero" TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="TextBlock.Background" Value="Orange" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="local:TextBlockBehavior.MyProperty" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="TextBlock.Background" Value="Transparent" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Given solution suits well if style triggers doing many things. In your case (to change background) it would be easier to simply make converter (or use another property in ViewModel, colors are ok to return, see e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36866955/1997232)) for each type to produce wanted background brush/color (e.g. `ColorToBackground`):

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding PropA, StringFormat=Running \{0\}}"
           Background="{Binding PropA, Converter=local:SomeTypeToBackground}" />
```